# Black Dot (like Dead pixel) under Note 8's Screen

Tags: screen

I bought a note 8 about 10 days ago.
Today after 10 days, I have a black dot under the first layer of display  that is still visible when the screen is off.
This dot is like a "dead pixel" but is visible even with screen off.
And i think there's a little space between OLED and this dot

How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: As it's still there with the phone off, this doesn't sound like an Android problem. You should ask the shop you bought the phone from.